# Markov inequality exercise measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

Let $u \in \cal{L}^1(\mu)$, $T$ A measure preserving map s.t.: $\int (u)  d\mu =\int u\circ Td\mu$.
$A_{n,\epsilon}=\{\frac{|u(T^n(x))|}{n^2} \gt \epsilon\}$.
$T^n=T\circ T\circ T…$ n times.

Prove $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mu(A_{n, \epsilon}) $ is finite.

My attempt:

By Markov inequality we get: $\mu(A_{n, \epsilon}) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int \frac{|u(T^n(x))|}{n^2} d\mu$, since $T$ is measure preserving we get: $|u(T^n(x))|\in \cal{L^1(\mu)}$.
Summing over n gives:

$\sum_{n\ge1}\mu(A_{n, \epsilon)} \le \sum_{n\ge 1} \epsilon^{-1}n^{-2}\int|u(T^n(x))|d\mu .$

This is the part where I am stuck. I know that all the integrals are finite but how do I ensure that summing over all the integrals stays finite? Can I make the integral independent of n? Or can I just state by assumption: $\int|u(T^n(x))|d\mu =\int|u|d\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is a measure preserving map, then for $n=1$ and $f$ measurable we have
$$\int_X f(T(x))\mu(dx)=\int_X f(x)\mu_T(dx)=\int_X f(x)\mu(dx)$$
Now suppose that for $n>1$ it holds that
$$\int_X f(T^{n-1}(x))\mu(dx)=\int_X f(x)\mu(dx)$$
We would have
$$\begin{aligned}\int_X f(T^{n}(x))\mu(dx)&=\int_X f(T^{n-1}(T(x)))\mu(dx)=\\&=\int_Xf(T(x))\mu(dx)=\\
&=\int_Xf(x)\mu(dx)\end{aligned}$$
Therefore by induction
$$\int_X f(T^n(x))\mu(dx)=\int_X f(x)\mu(dx),\,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Now set $f(x)=|u(x)|$ and you're done: $u$ is integrable so $|u|$ is too and
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n)\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\bigg(\int_X| u| d\mu\bigg)\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$